# Running Sidekiq on seperate EC2 instance using ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My question is, is that a major drawback of EBS ? In Heroku, I just need to write two lines in Procfile to do this. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalk actually recently added this functionality when deploying to their Amazon Linux 2 platform. See here for [details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).